# Sending an email to 2 variables in PHP

Tags: php

Im trying to send an email to 2 variables currently I have tried to add 3 emails to an array and put that into a variable and get the other email from the form, I then dont know how to put both of those variables together when sending so they each have their own "to" but this does not work or something doesnt and I dont know what?? And yes I have real emails that I use these are placeholders for this!!!

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = $_POST['LOGSE'];
    $email2 = array("test@test.com", "test@test.com", "test@test.com");
    $name = $_POST['full_name'];
    $eventtitle =  $_POST['EventT'];
    $InCharge =  $_POST['InCharge'];
    $Venue =  $_POST['Venue'];
    $VenY =  $_POST['VenR'];
    if($VenY != "Yes"){
        $ava = " Have not checked if";
    }
    else{
        $ava = "";
    }
    $dates = $_POST['dateS'];
    $datee = $_POST['dateE'];
    $adults =  $_POST['Adults'];
    $children =  $_POST['Children'];
    $catreq =  $_POST['CateReq'];
    if (catreq != ''){
        $catreq = $catreq;
    }
    else{
    $catreq = "No Catering Needed";

    }

    $logreq =  $_POST['LogReq'];
    if (logreq != ''){

    $logreq = $logreq;
    }
    else{
        $logreq = "No Logistic Equipment Needed";

    }
    $itreq =  $_POST['ITReq'];
    if (itreq != ''){

    $itreq = $itreq;
    }
    else{
    $itreq = "No IT Needed";

    }
    $tran =  $_POST['TransR'];
    if($tran != Yes){

        $tran = "NO ";


    }
    else{
        $tran = "";

    }
    $Risk =  $_POST['RiskR'];
    if($Risk != Yes){

        $Risk = "NO ";


    }
    else{
        $Risk = "";

    }
    $othern =  $_POST['OtherN'];

    // The Email:
    $from      = 'test@test.com';
    $to      = $email;
    $to      = $email2;
    $subject = 'Event Form ' .$eventtitle;
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: Event Form<test@test.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: test@test.com, test@test.com' . "\r\n";
    $body = '<html>
        <head>
            <title>Event</title>
            <style>
                h1 {
                    font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, 
AppleGothic, sans-serif;
                } 
                h3 {
                    font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, 
AppleGothic, sans-serif;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Event Details</h1>

            <h3>Name: '.$name.'</h3>
            <h3>Event Title: '.$eventtitle.'</h3>
            <h3>Event Manager: '.$InCharge.'</h3>
            <h3>Venue: '.$Venue.' - '.$ava.' Available</h3>
            <h3>Date Start: '.$dates.'</h3>
            <h3>Date End: '.$datee.'</h3>
            <h3>Adults Attending: '.$adults.'       Children Attending: 
'.$children.'</h3>
            <h3>Catering Requirements: '.$catreq.'</h3>
            <h3>Logistic Requirements/Equipment: '.$logreq.'</h3>
            <h3>IT Requirements: '.$itreq.'</h3>
            <h3>Other Notes: '.$othern.'</h3>
            <h3><font color="red">'.$tran.'</font>Transport Has Been 
Booked</h3>

        </body>
    </html>' . "\r\n";





    mail( $to, $subject, $body ,$headers );

        /* echo "An Email Has Been Sent<br>Thank You."; */
        header('Location: ./thanks.html');

     }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The $to in mail function should be a string. If there are more than one email address then those should be comma separated. In your case you might need to do like following.
    $to = $email . ','. implode(',', $email2);

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make sense:

```
$to      = $email;
$to      = $email2;
```

Parmaeter $to should be a string of comma-seperated email-addresses, e.g.:

```
$to = $email1 . ", " . $email2 . ", " . $email3;
```

Comment: Okay, I was looking for writing on this but could't find any, well not that i could understand. Will try this and get back to you, thank you :)

Comment: Be aware: With this approach each receiver can see the other receivers email-addresses. Therefore sometimes it is a good idea to send sepaerate emails for each reciever or use the BCC-field.

Comment: I'll give that a thought but its on a locked down subdomain at my work so hopefully it would't be an issue as staff are the only people who can get these emails

Comment: Also whilst I'm here would having the 2 $to break everything and completely not send emails or would one cancel out the other

Comment: @RyanDownes If you set a new value for a variable the variable has the new value and the value before that assignment is lost. Thus, you are sending your mail only to $email2. It is also not possible to use an array as input-parameter because the definition of the mail-function requires $to to be a string.

Comment: Yeah I tested that before you replied found that out haha, all corrected now

Answer (score 0):

Add email address with the comma

```
$email_to = "test@test.com,some@other.com,yet@another.net";
```

Also you can add

```
$headers = "Bcc: someone@domain.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `foreach` on the array:

```
foreach($email2 as $to){
    mail( $to, $subject, $body ,$headers );
}
```

Or like others are suggesting:

```
$to = $email.",".implode(",",$email2);
```